# How to download a website using WGET?

Tags: wget

I'm not sure if anyone on this forum can help me.

Is it a ridiculous idea for you all to show me the steps to download a website that requires a username and password, I currently have?

https://app.pushbuttonautomarketer.com/site/login.phtml

The problem is I am new to web scraping and its coding. After spending many hours trying to make sense of what I am doing, I only reached past the installation process in cmd.

What do you suggest I do to move forward?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: You could log in to the site on a regular computer, click remember me and then use the saved cookie in your `wget` command to get past the login screen by itself. *Please also consider whether scraping a site that requires a login is against their terms of use*

Comment: Thank you pigeonburger. for your reply. I know where to get the saved cookie, it may like like I understand what I am doing. But I am sorry, how am I going place the coding?

Answer (score 0):

This will save the cookie in a form and place where wget can retrieve it:

```
wget \
    --delete-after \
    --keep-session-cookies \
    --post-data 'email=<userID>&password=<password>' \
    --save-cookies=<filename> \
    https://<your login URL>
```

You can then invoke wget with the saved cookies (add whatever other options you need):

```
wget \
    --load-cookies=<filename> \
    https://<your website's base URL>
```